# Intellij keeps prompting for credentials with git under Windows

Tags: intellij-idea, git-push, git-clone, git-pull

I have intellij setup in Windows. My SCM is git. I am using git bash as my git client. Problem is I am not able to persist my password.

I have already tried the solution provided by Intellij. But doesn't fix my issue.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000047544-GIT-unable-to-remember-my-password

Answer (score 1):

we have to set the credential.helper configuration parameter of the git client (git bash) to make use of Windows Credential Manager to store our passwords. This can be enabled by executing

`git config --global credential.helper manager`